# Understanding thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm new to `java.util.concurrent` package therefore I'd like to ask an advice. I need to evaluate some operation within a ThreadPool, but I also need to cancel the concurrent evaluation. So, I tend to wrap the `ThreadPoolExecutor` into a `Future<T>` interface. Here is what I tried to do:

```
public class PooledFutureTask implements Future<List<Integer>> {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    private boolean cancelled;
    List<Integer> result;

    public PooledFutureTask(List<Runnable> runnables) {
        for (Runnable r : runnables)
            executor.execute(r);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        if (executor.shutdownNow().size() > 0)
            return cancelled = true;
        return executor.isTerminated() || executor.isShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return executor.isTerminated();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        while(true) {
            if (executor.isShutdown())
                return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        if (executor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            throw new TimeoutException();
        return result;
    }

}
```

But I'm not sure about that. Couldn't you point me out where I was wrong?

I'm using Java7.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: `while(true)` is the worst piece of code imaginable - **never** use it anywhere, it will produce unexpected deadlocks. This statement has a long history of being the root cause for bad/ unstable/buggy/applications. Evene *if* you somehow manage to create exit paths for virtually every imaginable circumstance (which is impossible) you still would have written code which is nigh-unreadable for actual developers.

Comment: @specializt I know, that's why I asked the question. But I couldn't find a better solution.

Comment: A **much** better solution : `final AtomicBoolean exit = new AtomicBoolean(false); while(false == exit.get()) { // your code here }`

Comment: Where is the `result` coming from?

Comment: Never place an `Executor` into the task itself as the `Executor` acts like a job queue, the instance have to exist regardless of tasks or the results (`Future`s). I think what you need to do  is extend `ExecutorService`. What do you really want to do? Concretely, cancel policy and execution policy should be shown explicitly.

Comment: @specializt `Thread.current().isInterrupted()` is the best and only solution against `while (true)`

Comment: @yanana Why not? Actually I have a bulk operation executaed concurrently. The result of the operation should be shared among all clients. So, if one client has already requested the result, and then the other client request the result too before the evaluation for the first client has been completed, I need to give them the same result requested by the first client.

Comment: actually thinking that `currentThread().isInterrupted()` "is the only solution" ... thats very delusional, ignorant and a pretty solid indicator for infinitesimal experience, possibly even knowledge. I recommend reading a good book about multi-threading in Java. Waiting for thread interruption is only a *last resort* which is never actually necessary since Java offers [atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html) and [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: @user3663882 Well, who instantiates this `Future`? Isn't it `ExecutorService`? `Future` is a result of a computation represented as `Callable` which is run by `ExecutorService`. So a `Future`'s life cycle is not the same as `ExecutorService`'s.